# How can I make a "live" counter in HTML?

Tags: html, counter

I am doing a project on the CO2 emissions of datacenters and want to incorporate my essay into a website with visuals. How could I go about creating a counter that counts up and adds a little image every time the counter goes up? Kind of like this website: https://www.internetlivestats.com/watch/co2-emissions/

Answer (score 1):

You can use `setInterval()` or `setTimout()`
check out documentation
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp

```
var count=0;
setInterval(()=>{
count++;
 //your logic here
},1000)//it will increment counter after 1 second you can change
```